# How to Compare Date and Time With Margin

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'd like to take a TimeCreated string value from a Windows event log, convert it to a useable datetime object, then search for all matching events up to the minute +/- say, two minutes: Get-WinEvent returns the date and time like this:

```
2/2/2020 09:04:22 AM
```

What would be the best way to

1. convert TimeCreated to something more useable (that also doesn't use AM/PM), and
2. do a comparison for events that have a time of +/- two minutes of that event (basically looking contextually)?

In other words, it would return events that have a TimeCreated value of the following:

```
2/2/2020 09:03:27 AM
2/2/2020 09:02:24 AM
2/2/2020 09:05:22 AM
```

But if TimeCreated were any of the following, it would NOT match (outside of +/- two minutes):

```
2/2/2020 09:06:27 AM
2/2/2020 09:02:20 AM
2/2/2020 09:08:22 AM
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are several examples on the internet and even here on SO about issues like this. Did you try so search for it?  You may (re-)read the help topic: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: the item returned by `Get-WinEvent` **_does not contain a date string_**. it contains a `[datetime]` object - and that means the `2/2/2020 09:04:22 AM` you see is entirely based on your locale settings for how to _display_ the object. try running this >>> `(Get-WinEvent -LogName system -MaxEvents 2)[0].TimeCreated.GetType()` <<< and you will find that it is NOT a string. [*grin*] instead, it is a date time object. my current result for this >>> `(Get-WinEvent -LogName system -MaxEvents 2)[0].TimeCreated` << is this `2020 February 13, Thursday 12:12:54 AM`.

Comment: Of course I searched for it, Olaf, otherwise I wouldn't have created an issue here on SO. Maybe I didn't search enough, or I could have used better keywords.

@Lee_Dailey thanks for clarifying that! That's definitely helpful. 

So I see I can manipulate that datetime object and change the format to how I want it; what's the best way to do the comparison +/- 2 minutes? 

That's the main part where I'm lost.

Comment: @BaliRobin - you are welcome! the best way to do comparisons of datetime stuff is to **_leave them as datetime objects._** PoSh knows how to compare/add/subtract such things, so you can easily do an `if ($StartTime -lt $TestTime -and $TestTime -lt $EndTime) {Do-Stuff}`/

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thank you! I'll give that a whirl!

Comment: @BaliRobin - you are most welcome ... and good luck! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an easy way to do this is by using Where-Object and -lt/-gt operators:

```
| ?{ $_.TimeCreated -lt ($event.TimeCreated + "00:02") -and $_.TimeCreated -gt ($event.TimeCreated + "-00:02") }
```

Comment: Equivalently, you could write `[Math]::Abs(($_.TimeCreated - $event.TimeCreated).TotalMinutes) -lt 2`, which you may find more or less complex, but definitely shorter.

Comment: Nice. Math was never my forte, haha. Thanks @BACON